# Uninstantiable; Callable when using Callable variables from a trait declaration

Tags: traits, raku

With this code, I'm trying to add a "logging" trait to a subroutine:

```
my &loggr = -> $event {
    state %store;
    %store{ DateTime.new( now ) } = $event;
}

multi sub trait_mod:<is>(Sub $s, :$logger){
    loggr( $s.name );
}

multi sub add( Int $a, Int $b) is logger {
    $a + $b;
}

say add(1,2);
```

However, I get the error:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling /home/jmerelo/Code/perl6/my-perl6-examples/is-logger-fail.p6
Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Uninstantiable; Callable)
at /home/jmerelo/Code/perl6/my-perl6-examples/is-logger-fail.p6:14
```

(line 14 would be the line where `add` is declared). Declaring `loggr` directly as a sub yields no error. Why am I getting this `Uninstantiable` error here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why am I getting this `Uninstantiable` error here?

When used after a `my` declaration, `=` (or `:=`) invokes assignment (or binding) at *run-time*. A trait applied to a compile-time sub declaration runs at *compile-time*, which comes first. So your trait calls `loggr` before it's initialized.

To fix that, you need to shift the variable initialization to compile-time, eg:

```
BEGIN &loggr = ...
```

or

```
constant &loggr = ...
```

---

While the error message reads like a low-level error, and it would be nice if it specifically mentioned `loggr` (but perhaps doesn't because it's low-level), it will hopefully make more sense now:

```
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ...
Cannot invoke this object (REPR: Uninstantiable; Callable)
```

Your code has asked to call `loggr` at compile-time. But while it *does* have the appropriate `Callable` type, it hasn't yet been initialized, so is uninstantiable at the time it is being asked to invoke it.